# postgres: temporary column default that is unique and not nullable, without relying on a sequence?

Tags: postgresql

1. Hi, I want to add a **unique, non-nullable** column to a table.
2. It
   **already has data**. I would therefore like to instantly populate the
   new column with unique values, eg 'ABC123', 'ABC124', 'ABC125', etc.
3. The data will eventually be wiped and
   replaced with proper data, so i don't want to introduce a **sequence**
   just to populate the default value.

Is it possible to generate a default value for the existing rows, based on something like `rownumber()`? I realise the use case is ridiculous but is it **possible** to achieve... if so how?

```sql
...
foo text not null unique default 'ABC'||rownumber()' -- or something similar?
...
```

Comment: "*The data will eventually be wiped and replaced with proper data*" - just do that *before* adding the uniqueness (or non-nullability) constraint

Comment: I have no control over what will be done with this model and when. I agree this seems like an unnecessary (or poorly-timed) stopgap. But it _did_ make me curious as to whether it's possible or not.

Comment: What's wrong with a sequence?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nothing; It just wasn't going to be used for anything after this hack and would just be detritus in the model (i couldn't remove it because the columns i used it to populate were dependants preventing deletion). In the end i said F it, and used a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be applied generate_series?

```
select 'ABC' || generate_series(123,130)::text;

 ABC123
 ABC124
 ABC125
 ABC126
 ABC127
 ABC128
 ABC129
 ABC130
```

**Variant 2** add column **UNIQUE** and **not null**

```
begin;
alter table test_table add column foo text not null default 'ABC';

with s as (select id,(row_number() over(order by id))::text t from test_table) update test_table set foo=foo || s.t from s where test_table.id=s.id;

alter table test_table add CONSTRAINT unique_foo1 UNIQUE(foo);

commit;
```

results

```
select * from test_table;
id | foo
----+------
  1 | ABC1
  2 | ABC2
  3 | ABC3
  4 | ABC4
  5 | ABC5
  6 | ABC6
```

Comment: getting error 'set-returning functions are not allowed in DEFAULT expressions'. (same for update expressions).

Comment: You did not say anything about using a function. Without seeing the code there is nothing that can be done to help. Post your code, as text - **no images**.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer even tho i used a sequence in the end because it's v helpful and does the job! @Belayer what are you talking about? I indeed did NOT say anything about using a function... because I'm not?